# Roland Microcube guitar amp damaged beyond repair?

Tags: audio, speakers

My power regulated ac/dc adapter broke the other day and my friend thought it was a good idea to cut the wire from the mains adapter, trim the ends and plug this directly into the mains. he then connected the adapter end to the microcube. the elctricity in the flat tripped out at the circuit breakers. Would the amp be completly wrecked after this happening or is there a part I can replace that will fix it?. I just bought a new ac/dc adapter, plugged it into the amp, but nothing is happening, seems like something has blown(?)

anyone got a suggestion?

UPDATE**..i took it apart and saw that next to the dc input socket there is what appears to be a blown fuse. it says next to it "T800mAL" and i saw this http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/800mA-Amp-T800mA-T800mAL-Fuse-AntiSurge-20x5mm-x-10-/360325684444  I dont have time to go and get one, is there another household device I could steal one from? I really need my amp tonight :(

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you cut the wire off of a wall wart or desk-style power adapter on the side of the block closer to the amp (which would be DC), and plugged it into AC?  Watch out - you're working with high voltage, and it sounds like you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I have a suggestion - find a new friend.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [manufacturer](http://www.roland.com/products/en/Micro-CUBE/specs.html) , the Microcube takes 9VDC input.

From what you described, your friend took a circuit expecting 9VDC and wired it directly into 120VAC (assuming you're in North America).

If this is the case, I don't need to rely on my >10 years in power supplies to tell you that this is a VERY BAD THING. Your friend has almost certainly destroyed the low-voltage electronics inside the amplifier by applying line voltage directly to a low-voltage DC circuit.

Properly-sized fuses blow as a consequence of something bad happening. I would expect that the AC application caused a short-circuit which opened the fuse.

If you intend to replace the fuse and try your luck again, you MUST ensure that you're using a 9VDC supply (preferably current-limited to less than 1A) to power the circuit. Otherwise, you'll simply pop the fuse again.

Comment: can i just bypass the fuse?

Comment: Bypassing fuses is almost never a good idea. As long as the root cause (short or bad component deeper down in the circuit) is not found and repaired, powering with a bypassed fuse will cause more trouble than you already have (i.e. break lots more things). Once the root cause is found, the fuse must be replaced with the same type and rating. Imagine something else breaks later on: You want the proper fuse to protect the circuit from big damage and your house from fire.

Comment: Do NOT bypass the fuse. Full stop. No debate or questioning will be accepted.

Comment: It's not a matter of killing yourself, it's a matter of killing things in your amplifier that haven't been killed yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try going to a radio shack, they should have some fuses, one will probably fit.

You might also find a good fuse at a home improvement store. These fuses should be affordable and easy to access today.